# Url helper for full url in asp.net mvc-3

Tags: asp.net, urlhelper, asp.net-mvc-3

Writing

```
@Url.Content("~/Something/Something.html")
```

in razor renders

```
/AppFolder/Something/Something.html
```

Is there a way to render the full URL like `http://www.something.com/AppFolder/Something/Something.html` without atrocious hacks? (like storing the protocol and domain in the `AppConfig`, and concatenate the string to it)

Is there a helper like `@Url.FullPath("~/asdf/asdf")` or similar?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?  I'm looking for the same thing! Any help appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestions to use Url.Action in Mono? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497900/how-to-use-url-action-in-mono

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The @Url.RouteURL()  does not quiet answer this question.  It does work for named routes but falls short for arbitrary virtual paths.
Here is quick helper method that generates full outbound url. You can create overloads for various schemes (http[s]) depending on the degree of control desired.

```
public static class UrlHelperExtension
{
    public static string ContentFullPath(this UrlHelper url,string virtualPath)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        Uri requestUrl = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;

        result = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",
                               requestUrl.Scheme,
                               requestUrl.Authority, 
                               VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(virtualPath));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was an old question! You might get a badge for this :D

Answer (score 26):

See [this blog post](http://www.captaincodeman.com/.net/mvc/rendering/routing/2010/02/03/absolute-urls-using-mvc-without-extension-methods/) for the answer.

Basically, all you need to do it include the protocol parameter e.g.

```
Url.Action("About", "Home", null, "http")
```

Comment: This is a better answer than using `String.Format`. +1

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needing to build URLs in WebAPI 2.2 and/or MVC5, this worked for me:

```
// works in a controller
var requestUri = this.Request.RequestUri;
// just the http/s and the hostname; ymmv
string baseUrl = requestUri.Scheme + "://" + requestUri.Authority + "/";
// build your url for whatever purpose you need it for
string url = baseUrl + "SomeOtherController?id=" + <some_magic_value>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper to produce a full url, including protocol. Note the first lowercase in `url.Action`.

```
var url = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var fullUrl = url.Action("YourAction", "YourController", new { id = something }, protocol: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme);
```

**Output**

`https://www.yourdomain.com/YourController/YourAction?id=something`