# How to include absolute URL for JavaScript, CSS and Menu Items

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3, templates

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 3 web application. As a part of integration with third party application, we need to provide a master page (template) for our web application which they will use to inject necessary data on the page. The third party will poll our template every few minutes and update if any thing changed.

For this to work, all the JavaScript, CSS and menu links must be absolute URL to our domain name so that if user clicks the link. All JavaScript and CSS will refer to resources living on our domain.

Given that our web application will be hosted in different environments e.g. DEV, UAT, QA and Production (with actual real domain name). Could someone help me how we can provide a absolute URL for CSS, JavaScript and menu links that would work on all environments?

Comment: I believe you are asking a way to dynamically write the current domain to create the absolute path?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Url helper for full url in asp.net mvc-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089915/url-helper-for-full-url-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: Yep dynamic write absolute URL for js and css .